# Why A Map is not a true Collection?

Tags: java, oop, collections, dictionary

I was reading Java Collection Framework at its [official website](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/index.html).
There is one point - **"A Map is not a true Collection"**
What does it mean ? Why map is not a part of Collection ?
Then I came to know Map does not extends Collection. What is the purpose of doing this ? It would be better if Map is a part of Collection, isn't it ?
Please refer below hierarchy for Collection framework :-
[image]

Comment: Fine. The duplicates are duplicates of each other.

Answer (score 3):

A `Map` cannot be a `Collection` because their semantics are at odds. The closest thing to "collectionness" for a `Map` is when it is viewed as an `Set<Map.Entry<K,V>>`. You can get that as a *collection view* of the map by calling `map.entrySet()`; however it would cause more trouble than good if the `Map` itself implemented the complete `Collection` API. For example, the method `remove(Object)` is defined in both `Collection` and `Map`, but with incompatible semantics. The names of such methods would have to be warped, affecting all `Collection`s, just to fit the awkward case of `Map`.